# How to deploy non-function changes / helper files to cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We can deploy specific functions using command like:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:addMessage,functions:makeUppercase
```

This will also upload the folder with other files as well.

My question is how do I deploy only folders changes without deploying functions?

e.g. I have functions\template folder which contains a bunch of email templates.

I would like to deploy just this folder changes to cloud functions. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

certainly using firebase CLI you can't deploy a function without sending everything. the cli doesn't know the function dependencies then it will bundle (zip) the entire folder and it will create/update the function in GCP.

Also, there are performance implication on the way firebase deploy functions into GCP. A work around is to make every function it's own node module and deploy them independently using gcloud https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy

will also recommend to take a look at https://functions.store, their way of create function work similar to what gcloud does

Comment: What are the performance implications the way firebase deploy functions into GCP, do you know? And the link you posted in the last paragraph does not work.

Comment: I fixed the link, sorry. For performance implication since a "function" deployment might contain unnecessary dependencies and sometimes run unnecessary implementation that belongs to a different function that could end up slowing down the cold start of a function execution

Answer (score 0):

Deploying only selected files/folders to Cloud Functions is not possible. It's not possible to update your code and skip updating the execution environment of the function as Cloud Function is serverless and managed by Google. As stated in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying#deployment),

> Deployments work by uploading an archive containing your function's source code to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. Once the source code has been uploaded, Cloud Build automatically builds your code into a container image and pushes that image to Container Registry. Cloud Functions uses that image to create the container that executes your function.

And since container images are [immutable](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/best-practices-for-operating-containers#immutability), it is not possible to edit a revision. In order to apply changes to your function, it has to be rebuilt every deployment.